# securing SPA multi-tenant SaaS application

Tags: authentication, angularjs, spring-security, saas, single-page-application

I need some help with securing a single page multi-tenant saas application.

Questions:
1) What is the best way to implement it? I am trying the build the application using angularjs, spring mvc and REST.
2) Can this be done using Spring Security? Any example with creating login page and securing REST, calls will be helpful?

I have found a sample for implementing spring security with Spring JPA (http://krams915.blogspot.com/2012/01/spring-security-31-implement_3065.html) but it is not for SPA and SaaS.

I understand this a very broad question but i am new to SPA, REST and SaaS so any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I have already participated in two projects with SPA and security aspects. Last of them was GWT + Spring Security. I am sure that you can use successfully Angular and Spring Security together.

Unfortunately there is no built-in config parameter 'we are in SPA mode' in Spring Security AFAIK. So some tweaking / conf from Spring Security side will be necessary. Example:
imagine that during login you call built-in into Spring Security login controller. In a case of successfull authentication by default user will be redirected to index page, where in a case of failure it will be redirected to corresponding error page. It is a normal behavior for standard web applications that will be not so useful for SPA web applications. In a case of SPA you need to detect AJAX call and print JSON with username / roles for successfull cases or send 401 code for failures (then detect 401 in JS and show corresponding error). You can use corresponding extention points from Spring Security to do so: `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and `AuthenticationFailureHandler`.

Some another thing to tweak: by default after session expiration user will be redirected to login page (and SPA app receive login page as a response to the next AJAX call).

Looking into my personal exprience general guide will be like so: after login load list of roles into JS. Use it to show / hide corresponding components on UI side. **Apply the same list of restrictions on server side too**. To make sure that user do not edit JS in browser (although in a case of minified JS of some medium size app it will very complex task). On the server side you must choose between:

1. Secure URLs of AJAX calls
2. Secure some Java methods.

I prefer second one (secure business methods on services). I think it is more convinient because normally we want secure business operations, not some endpoints. As adwantage you will be able expose your business logic via some other protocol, and security will be there already. From other side I can imagine some business requirement to have different permissions for different endpoints / protocols. So it depends more on your actual situation.

Lage size JS applications must be splitted into modules. To decrease direct dependencies it may be better to use events insted of direct calls to cummunicate between modules. There are interesting thoughts of Addy Osmany about how to do security in these coditions. I did not found good link to it, maybe [this](http://addyosmani.github.io/aura/) or [this](http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/) will be helpfull (search "permission").

Feel free to post any questions. Good luck.